# How to open any link in our webview instead of chrome from WhatsApp or other apps

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

How to open any link in our webview like when we click on any link on whatsapp, Instagram, Facebook it directly start loading/opening in chrome so instead of opening link in chrome how to open in in our webview app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.